# Processing library CSV keeps adding rows even if condition not fulfilled

Tags: java, csv, processing

**USING THE PROCESSING LIBRARY WITH THEIR** `Table` **OBJECT**

I have set the code so that it creates a new row in a Table object `def` only when a condition is fulfilled inside a loop, however, it just adds a new row each time the code iterates through the loop:

```
for (int i=0; i!=data.getRowCount(); i++) {   //data is my original table object (37 rows)
 if (i%3==0) {
  def.addRow();   // def is my result object, which should have about 1/3 of the elements
 }
}

print(def.getRowCount());   //will output the same as data.getRowCount()
```

The problem doesn't seem to be inside the loop, since if you ask it to `print()` something, it will do it about 1/3 of `data.getRowCount()` times. However, by just running: `print(def.getRowCount())`, the result will be the same as `data.getRowCount()` when it should be around 1/3.

Full code:

```
Table data, def;

void setup() {

data=loadTable("binance_data.csv", "header");
def=new Table();

 def.addColumn("Year", Table.INT);
 def.addColumn("Month", Table.INT);
 def.addColumn("Day", Table.INT);
 def.addColumn("Hour", Table.INT);
 def.addColumn("Minute", Table.INT);
 def.addColumn("Second", Table.INT);

 def.addColumn("Pair", Table.STRING);
 def.addColumn("Side", Table.STRING);
 def.addColumn("Price", Table.FLOAT);
 def.addColumn("Amount", Table.FLOAT);

for (int i=0; i!=data.getRowCount(); i++) {
 if (data.getString(i, "Status").equals("FILLED")) { //this is the actual condition.

  String[] blocks=data.getString(i, "Date(UTC)").split(" ");
  String[] dates=blocks[0].split("-");
  String[] times=blocks[1].split(":");

  def.addRow();

  def.setInt(i, "Year", int(dates[0]));
  def.setInt(i, "Month", int(dates[1]));
  def.setInt(i, "Day", int(dates[2]));

  def.setInt(i, "Hour", int(times[0]));
  def.setInt(i, "Minute", int(times[1]));
  def.setInt(i, "Second", int(times[2]));

  def.setString(i, "Pair", data.getString(i, "Pair"));
  def.setString(i, "Side", data.getString(i, "Side"));
  def.setFloat(i, "Price", data.getFloat(i, "Average Price"));
  def.setFloat(i, "Amount", data.getFloat(i, "Order Amount"));
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Print `i` before and in the `if-statement`.

Comment: What you are showing here works fine. Can you show more of the code (like where `def` gets created, or otherwise manipulated)?

Comment: @Cadin I just edited and added the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the row data using the `i` variable, you're putting the data into that specific numbered row.

So, even if your condition is only triggered once, if `i` is 37 at that time then you'll be putting the data into the 37th row (with blank rows filling in before). Remember that `i` continues to increment every loop even when the condition is not met.

To fix it, you can get the row that is returned from [`addRow`](https://processing.org/reference/Table_addRow_.html) and add data using that specific reference, instead of using `i` to insert into a numbered row.

```
TableRow newRow = def.addRow();
newRow.setInt("Year", int(dates[0]));
newRow.setInt("Month", int(dates[1]));
newRow.setInt("Day", int(dates[2]));

// etc...
```